# If "who" is for people, which word conveys a similar expression for animals?

Tags: grammar

> Martin's dog is the one **which** was hurt in the stampede.

Is this statement correct? I'm told that we should be using "that" in place of "which".

Comment: In this particular case, you use "that." You can use which or that for animals, though. For explanation, search for "comma" before "which" and "that". It's about restrictive and nonrestrictive clauses.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an article showing the difference in usage between clauses with **that** and **which**.
https://getitwriteonline.com/articles/which-vs-that/

According to their explanation, the clause with 'that' points directly at a specific subject while the clause with 'which' just attaches an additional description. In our case, the version with **that** is self-explanatory while the other version (with *which*) rather refers to some earlier part of conversation and just adds some detail:

> *(Yes,)* Martin's dog was the one, *and* it/he/she was hurt in the stampede.

Comment: Animals are frequently anthropomorphised, especially people's pets and animal characters in cartoons and books such as The Wind in the Willows. As such, they are treated as personalities **who** take **who** as a pronoun. Certainly, my seven dogs and 4 cats would be most offended to be **which(ed)**

Comment: You've excluded the possibility that the dog is female. (You missed *she* as a pronoun in your example sentence.)

Comment: OK, I'll add it.